# Is Maven really flexible?

Tags: maven

I understand how Maven works with .java files in src/java/main. But may it be used for a more general case? Let us put it more abstract: Suppose I already have some a.exe that reads some (not necessarily only .java) sources from directories A1, A2, A3 and puts some files (maybe some are generated .java) to directories B1, B2. I also have some b.exe that currently reads files from B1, B2, B3 and generates something else. Some more similar steps. (A real life problem stands behind).

I would like to write a POM.xml file so that maven will do this work. Is that possible? I assume that a.exe and b.exe should be warped as maven plugings. 
Next, in Maven docs I see :

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```

What bothers me is that "sourceDirectory" looks by itself as a hard coded name. Will Maven accept A1 and A2 tags instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Will you consider accepting some of your previous questions, so that other people will be more willing to answer you?)

Maven stress for Convention over Configuration.  You can treat `sourceDirectory` as one of the conventions, which we have predefined some elements to use with the (Java) compiler plugin.

What you want to do can be achieved.  You can write a plugin/MOJO yourself, which read from whatever directory you want and invoke whatever external exe you want.  By having reasonable default values in your MOJO, you can have your project POM look something like

```
<project>
  :
  :
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>yourPluginGroup</group>
        <artifactId>generate-A-data</artifactId>
        <!-- if you want extra configuration, you can have <configuration> elements -->
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>yourPluginGroup</group>
        <artifactId>generate-B-data</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
<project>
```

Not that bad huh?

However, it is quite questionable to say whether Maven is "flexible".  I believe flexibility is never the aim of Maven.  Maven is specialized for building, it defines different skeletons for you to follow (e.g. build phases, dependency scopes), you can never make Maven as "flexible" as other script-based tools like Ant.

Comment: OK. So effectively I may ignore "sourceDirectory" at all.

Comment: yup kind of, and probably you may need to 'disable' the default plugins too (e.g. jar and compiler plugin for JAR artifact type)

Comment: Maybe. However some two of the steps of my current process call javac and the last minus one creates jar. We shall see. With ant it is pretty straightforward ...

Comment: The fact that generate-B-data follows generate-A-data in your example - is it sufficient that they are both executed and in the same order?

Comment: @Dima I believe what you are doing is also straight-forward in Maven.  We usually treat that as source or resource generation.  There are plenty plugins doing similar stuff (e.g. reading from XSD and generate Java Source for XML binding).  It is never said that we can only have different kind of source code in "sourceDirectory".  Different plugin has its own convention (e.g. a plugin generate Java source from WSDL can read source from `src/main/wsdl`, etc).  Honestly from your OP, I thought u wanna use Maven to build non-Java project.  You extra information in comment now make more sense.

Comment: Moving forward somehow. Now my pom first executes maven-compiler-plugin on some source directories (I know how to configure that) then (step2) my own plugin that generates more java. Next (step 3) I want to run maven-compiler-plugin on that new directory. I failed to write a pom that works. It complains on all combinations I tried starting with "duplicate plugin". Or in the best case tries to start execution with step 2. Means sets some order of execution on his own. Far from flexible.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: NO, MAVEN IS NOT FLEXIBLE. Here is a simple task I could not solve even with the help from all the maven forums of this world: Write a POM that

1. compiles some directory full of Java files
2. does something else (if you please - executes a sample Hello World Mojo plugin)
3. compiles some other directory with some other Java files.

   ```
    NO WAY !
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this without writing plugins, by binding the exec plugin and the compiler plugin to the 'generate-sources' or 'process-classes' phases. The build helper plugin might also be useful for adding source paths.

For the original case, you could try the following bindings:

- build-helper-maven-plugin bound to the initialize phase, adding any necessary source directories (eg B1 and B2)
- exec-maven-plugin bound to the generate-sources phase, with two executions, one for a.exe and one for b.exe

For the Hello World Mojo case, what if you add the following to the process-classes phase (in order)?

- Hello World Mojo plugin
- Build Helper plugin to add source directory
- Compiler plugin

The only downside I can see is that the first source directory will be recompiled. But the compiler should be smart enough to know that nothing has changed, and whether it's a problem depends on why you actually want to do this. Why do you need the class files from directory A before you run Hello World? Perhaps you're really looking at two separate pieces of code that should become separate modules?